# update website with text on my local pc

Tags: web

Apologies if this is a basic question but I was unsure what to search to try and get a answer. If someone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful.

Basically this is what I want to do.

I have a pretty much blank website that I want to display text out of a text file on my local pc to at regular intervals (The contents of the text file will change regularly). What are the things that I'll need to learn to do this?

I read up on how you can do this with AJAX but as I understand it the text file would have to be on the server, which in this case it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that this a month old but since no one has really paid any attention to it, might as well answer it.

It really doesn't make sense to keep it in your local PC. Because for your web app to be able to access that text resource you will have to have your local machine accessible from the outside world. If you want it that way, you create a webserver like application in your local machine, get it accessible via a public domain then access that with a (hopefully) secure GET request from your hosted application.

Simplest solution I can think of and a saner way to do this would be

Save it in a database in the hosting server. Whenever you need to update the text, you change the value in the DB using a DB administration application such as phpmyadmin that is also hosted from that same machine (but hopefully you restrict IP access to phpmyadmin only to yourself, but that is another matter). Better yet you can always make a fancy CMS app to make things easier.

Or if you still find that a tad to hard why not just put in the source code, have it versioned and update it whenever you need to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I learnt a lot about webpages from trying this.

What I ended up doing was writing a autoit script that would upload the text file to my ftp at certain times, at that point my site used wordpress, so I got a wordpress plugin that would replace shortcode with the contents of my text file.

I don't really like that method though as it requires me to upload a heap of different txt files etc for different data. So I'm thinking when I get time I'll probably write the webpage myself from scratch, but this time upload a json file and use jquery/ajax to display it